# iOS Dropbox sync before app quits

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I'm trying to sync files created in my app to Dropbox, however it seems the syncing only happens after the app **quits**, and not in real time when files are created and moved between locations in different folders in the app or created/deleted. Is there a certain call I have to make for instance? Appreciate your help!

Below is the code I am using for syncing:

```
-(void)createFilePathinFolder:(NSString *)folderName FileName:(NSString *)fileName {

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *folder = [self localDocumentsRootPath];

if (![folderName isEqualToString:@"root"]) {
    folder = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
}

NSString *file = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:file]) {
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:file contents:[@"0" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];
}

//Insert to FileTable
[[DBHelper shared]insertToFileTableWithFolder:folderName FileName:fileName MetaFileName:nil Tag:nil Title:nil];

if ([NetworkHelper shared].canSyncWithCloud) {
    NSString *filePathStr = [folderName stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];;

    if ([folderName isEqualToString:@"root"]) {
        filePathStr = fileName;
    }

    DBPath *filePath = [[DBPath root] childPath:filePathStr];
    DBError *error;
    DBFile *destFile =[[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:filePath error:&error];

    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

    [destFile writeData:fileData error:&error];

    //[destFile writeContentsOfFile:file shouldSteal:NO error:&error];

    [destFile close];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error when creating file %@ in Dropbox, error description:%@", fileName, error.description);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error checking is all wrong. Your code should be more like this:

```
DBPath *filePath = [[DBPath root] childPath:filePathStr];
DBError *error = nil;
DBFile *destFile =[[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:filePath error:&error];
if (destFile) {
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
    if (![destFile writeData:fileData error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error when writing file %@ in Dropbox, error description: %@", fileName, error);
    }
    [destFile close];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error when creating file %@ in Dropbox, error description: %@", fileName, error);
}
```

The file should sync right away with the code that you have. This assumes you have properly linked your app to an account and all.

What version of the Dropbox Sync API are you using? 1.0.7 has some potential networking issues. I have a beta of 1.0.8 that seems to solve these issues. You may need to wait until 1.0.8 comes out.

You can verify if Dropbox is hung. While running your app in the debugger, wait a minute after the file has been created. If the file doesn't appear, pause your app in the debugger and look at all of the threads. You should see one or more dropbox related threads. If one looks blocked with a reference to `dbx_cfhttp_request` then you have hit a bug in the Dropbox framework. Putting your device in Airplane mode for 10-15 seconds then turning Airplane mode off again should kick it back into gear.